# C program freeze at fprintf ( large amounts of data )

Tags: c

I am attempting to write the clipboard contents to a file, but for some reason the program is freezing.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("tmp.code","w");
fprintf(fp,getclip()); /*writes*/

fclose(fp);

char* getclip(){

    HANDLE clip;
    if (OpenClipboard(NULL)){
        clip = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        CloseClipboard();
        return clip;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Since `getclip()` returns an `int`, and since the signature for `fprintf()` doesn't support an `int` in the named parameters... I think what you're doing wrong is you're ignoring your compiler output.

Comment: What do you expect `fprintf` to do with an integer as format string?

Comment: the function signature of fprintf is int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );

Comment: You're expecting this to work by magic. You never wrote any code to even extract the clipboard contents much less write them to a file. You did get a handle to them, but you never wrote any code to do anything with that handle.

Comment: The current code is working with small chunks of clipboard data.

Comment: @GabrielGray Then your question should be asking why the current code works at all. That's a hell of a mystery. My best guess -- the handle just happens to be a pointer to some of the data in the clipboard -- by sheer luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `getclip()` returns an `int`, and `fprintf` expects pointer to char. It is trying to access an invalid memory position: you're returning a `HANDLE` as `int` and then `fprintf` interprets that as a memory address to read characters from.

Please look at your compiler errors and warnings and fix your code.

Comment: I have edited my code and it's the same problem... work with small data, big data won't work